# asp.net MVC5 - Dependency Injection and AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I searched a long time for a solution for my problem. I have a custom AuthorizeAttribute that needs a Dependency to a "Service" that has access to a DbContext. 
Sadly the Dependency Injection did not work in the custom AuthorizeAttribute and was always null.

I came up with an (for me) acceptable solution. Now I want to know if my solution can cause unforeseen behaviour?

**Global.asax.cs**

```
 CustomAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeServiceFactory = () => unityContainer.Resolve<AuthorizeService>();
```

**CustomAuthorizeAttribute.cs**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public static Func<AuthorizeService> AuthorizeServiceFactory { get; set; }

        public Privilege Privilege { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!authorized)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return AuthorizeServiceFactory().AuthorizeCore(httpContext, Privilege);
        }
    }
```

**AuthorizeService.cs**

```
public class AuthorizeService
{
    [Dependency]
    public UserService UserService { private get; set; }

    public bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext, Privilege privilege)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = UserService.FindByName(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        return UserService.UserHasPrivilege(user.Id, privilege.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is this an acceptable solution? Will I run into nasty problems in the future or is there maybe a better way to use Dependency Injection in a custom AuthorizeAttribute?

Answer (score 28):

> I have a custom AuthorizeAttribute that needs a Dependency to a
>   "Service" that has access to a DbContext. Sadly the Dependency
>   Injection did not work in the custom AuthorizeAttribute and was always
>   null.

An implementation of `IControllerFactory` in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace creates instances your *Controllers* for web requests. The Controller Factory uses `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` to resolve dependencies in each controller.

However, *ActionFilters/Attributes* in the [MVC pipeline](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/LYHK270114-Detailed-ASP.NET-MVC-Pipeline.html) are not created from the Controller Factory so dependencies are not resolved using `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver`. This is why your dependency was always `null`.

Now, `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver` is `public` and `static` so you can access it yourself.

```
    public class AuthorizeService : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private UserService UserService
        {
            get
            {
                return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<UserService>();
            }
        }

        public bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext, Privilege privilege)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = UserService.FindByName(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            return UserService.UserHasPrivilege(user.Id, privilege.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Assuming your `UserService`has a dependency scope of *WebRequest*, i.e. its lifetime is *One Per web request* and tied to the lifetime of `HttpContext` of a web request this will not construct a new `UserService` if one has been resolved previously or after if this is the first time `UserService` has been resolved for the given web request.

Comment: I agree with this solution

Comment: I had the same issue and above answer was helpful. But since I'm using `Autofac`, they provide a way to resolve dependency in action filter through provider 
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html?highlight=filter#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters"


but the problem I was running into when using the above provider, my `UserService` has a dependency on `DbContext`, it throws an error 
`The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed error
r'

only when I hit browser refresh button before letting the previous request to finish

Answer (score 17):

In ASP.NET Core you can request services easily as below:

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        // if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        // {
        //     context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        //     return;
        // }

        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(UserService)) as UserService;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not asp net core. The differences in architecture are too deep.

Comment: That's why I mentioned "ASP.NET Core". I added this answer here because I guessed many people like me would end up here for similar problem in "ASP.NET Core" :-)

Comment: Thanks Majid. I'm wondering is there some downside to getting services this way? If you could shed some light on what's happening here I'd appreciate it. I don't feel confident using it without understanding even though the result is what I want it to be.

Comment: @Lukas whats happening here is that `RequestServices` is a property of type `IServiceProvider` which is automagically configured and set to the `IServiceProvider` that was constructed from the `IServiceCollection` defined and registered in your DI set up. (Startup.cs for ASP.NET Core).

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this:

[ASP.NET Web API and dependencies in request scope](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/asp-net-web-api-and-dependencies-in-request-scope/)

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
{
    var requestScope = filterContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
    _userService = requestScope.GetService(typeof(IUserService)) as IUserService;
}

//
// Summary:
//     Retrieves the System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope for the given request
//     or null if not available.
//
// Parameters:
//   request:
//     The HTTP request.
//
// Returns:
//     The System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope for the given request or null
//     if not available.
public static IDependencyScope GetDependencyScope(this HttpRequestMessage request);
```