# Implement Unity MVC 5 dependency injection in ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, actionfilterattribute

I'm trying to inject this user service via Unity (mvc5) in an actionfilter but it is null. How can I implement this?

```
public class TestFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // this is always null
    [Dependency]
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

    // other members
}
```

Comment: Have you registered `UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider` on the  `FilterProviders` ?

Comment: Hi Sam no I have not, how can I do this please?

Comment: Here is an [explanation and a suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31696909/1062224) to a similar question that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must register `UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider` as a `FilterProvider` first.

Modify the `App_Start` > `UnityMvcActivator`'s Start method like this:

```
public static void Start()
{
    var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

    FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
    FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
}
```

If you could not find the method. You probably installed wrong or out of date package. consider installing `Install-Package Unity.Mvc` on the package manager console.